# Handling exceptions from a json request with ELMAH

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am using ELMAH to handle expception in my MVC project. All is working fine, except for when the request is an ajax request.

The exception is captured and logged but when I do a response.redirect to the error page, the redirect doesn't happen and the error message is displayed on the same page, overlapping the existing content.

Here is the code :

this is the elmah code to catch exceptions. I assign the value "Y" if it's an Ajax request

```
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        context.HttpContext.Session["IsAjax"] = "Y";
    }
    var e = context.Exception;
    if (!context.ExceptionHandled
                     || RaiseErrorSignal(e) 
                            || IsFiltered(context))
                        return;
     LogException(e);
```

And in my Global asax file

In the ErrorLog_Logged method I store the GUID returned from ELMAH in a session variable to later
display the id to the user so they can mail the GUID and I can see the exception quering the GUID against the appropriate elmah table in the database.

```
     protected void ErrorLog_Logged(object sender, ErrorLoggedEventArgs args)
     {
             var id = args.Entry.Id;
             Session["ErrorId"] = id.ToString();
     }
```

and in the application_Error method I do the following

```
     protected void Application_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Error/Index");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong. The redirect doesn't work and the error message is displayed on top of the existing page.

My existing page has a bunch of jquery tabs.

I really can't get my head around this. If anyone knows the answer, I will greatly apprecite it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix your tags: this is a .net, asp.net-mvc-2 question.